# jQuery .live and page refresh issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this code fails to prevent a page refresh?

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var mytarget = me.attr('href');
    var is_link_to_self = mytarget.indexOf("index.php");
    if(is_link_to_self !== false) {
        me.live('click', function() {
            $('#content').load(mytarget);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but something like this would be simpler:

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
  if ( $(this).attr('href').indexOf("index.php") > -1 )
  {
    $('#content').load( $(this).attr('href') );
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: It did it! +1 Good real life application of KISS, thanks. But, I still wonder why the original code failed.

Comment: @Majid because you bound `live()` to an object instead of a selector, as pointed out in multiple answers.

Comment: Just to note, that will bind an event handler to all anchors. It might be a good idea to filter them down to the ones you need: `$("a[href*='index.php']").live("click"...` and then there's no need for the condition within the handler.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is nothing gets bound to your anchors because of the following condition:

```
if(is_link_to_self !== false) {
```

which should be:

```
if(is_link_to_self !== -1) {
```

`indexOf` will return a -1 when no match occurs which is falsy but not exactly false (as in the `false` boolean value), so that condition will never evaluate to true.

EDIT: I would suggest the following more concise approach:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
   return this.href.indexOf('index.php') !== -1; 
}).live("click", function(e) {
   $("#content").load(mytarget);
   e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Although this *is* true, it has nothing to do with why the code is not working. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/jLeFy/)

Comment: Good catch, changed it to `-1` and tested with `console.log(me);`. Now it correctly selects links, but still the page refresh problem persists :(

Comment: @Majid - Also, that code needs to have a `$(document).ready(...` wrap to ensure that the binding will take place when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 2):

indexOf operator returns int and not boolean, you should be checking for -1 instead, check here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp

Comment: Changed it to `-1`, still the problem is unsolved (read my comment under karim79's answer.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Aron Rotteveel, you need to call live on a selector :

```
$('a[href*="index.php"]').live('click', function() {
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: +1 Simple and elegant, only, the the correct selector is `$('a[href*="index.php"]')`

Comment: You're right. ~= means contains word. I'll change the answer.